# Which way round do I mount an angle grinder wheel

Tags: angle-grinder

The disc on this angle grinder was jamming against the guard. It has a recess in the centre, like this [image]
 Should the hollow part be facing away or towards the open side of the grinder, or is the rule that the side with writing on always faces up?
 My Bosch manual doesn't even say which side should face up, can anybody provide trustworthy references to mounting a disc

Comment: I've always mounted those with the hollow facing out, irrespective of where the writing is.

Comment: @brhans That's what I suspected suspected, since originally the wheel was mounted with the hollow facing down which jammed it up

Answer (score 6):

The hollow is meant to be mounted outward. This is so that the nut sits at or below flush, allowing the grinding face to be used without obstruction.